# Region codes abbreviations csv

Tags: csv, standards, abbreviation

I tried google but cannot find region codes abbreviations csv files. Does anyone know where can i find it. example `new south wales`, abbrev is `nsw` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing to that I've ever used, I obtained from airport data:

http://www.ourairports.com/data/

You'd want the regions csv (I can at least see New South Wales is present).

I'd be careful about using it for anything particularly critical though =D